# Sublime Text. How to wrap a piece of text with a span tag using snippets?

Tags: sublimetext3

How do I get this

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
```

to this

```html
<span class="responsive-line">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span> consectetur adipisicing elit
```

in the quickest possible way?

I know in notepadd ++ you can set up a snippet, select the text and click on your snippet to wrap the selection in a tag.  Is this possible in Sublime?

Answer (score 0):

This is already built-in to Sublime. Highlight the text you want, then select **`Edit -> Tag -> Wrap Selection With Tag`**. The first word you type will be the tag's name (`span`) then you can continue typing `class="responsive-line"` or whatever else you need in the opening tag.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that's done the business for me.